# What is this extra source for Sappho 31 Campbell / 2 Edmonds?

Tags: greek, poetry, text-corpus, sappho

I just noticed that [Campbell](https://www.scribd.com/doc/34720745/Sappho-and-Alcaeus-Loeb), listing sources for Sappho 31 Campbell / 2 Edmonds, besides Longinus, mentions also `P.S.I. (v. fr. 213B)`. I looked on [PSI online](http://www.psi-online.it/home), but nothing with the number 213 in its denomination seems to contain a literary text. So what is this source? And is there a scan (or perhaps raw transcription) of it available online?

**Update**

Could it be [this one](http://www.psi-online.it/images/orig/PSI%20XV%201470%20r.jpg?1316722594), which is termed in the image name as `PSI XV 1470 r`? I mean, the names don't match because Campbell has a number 213B whereas this has number 1470, and Campbell says `v` (which I assume means `verso`), whereas the image name has `r` (which I assume means `recto`), but this looks like a very valid source for the poem at hand, so is this the extra source listed by Campbell or does Campbell ignore this one and list yet another source for this poem? And in the latter case, what is that source? And in the former, why the name differences?

**Extra: papyrus transcription**

> Μ€ΟΒΟΝΒ̣ΟϹΟΙΛ[
>   ωΤωΝΚΑΙΟΤΡΟ[
>   ΤΟΥϹωΜ  ̣ΤΟϹΚ  ̣[
>   ΚΑΙΜ€ΤẠΤΑΥΤΑΤ[
>   ΦΗϹΙṆ ΧΛωΡΟΤ[
>   ]  ̣ΙΑϹ€ΜΜΙΤ€θ̣[  *
>   ]ΛΙΓωΔΕΠΙΔ€[
>   ]  ̣Ν̣ΟΜ̣ΕΜΑΥ[  * *

- The theta is uncertain because it doens't close and so it llooks like another epsilon.
- - The nu is half cut off, and the mu has the left stroke vanished (faded, probably).

So that would read:

> ἐ]μὲ ὁ βόνβος, ὁ ἴλ[ιγγος
>   ὤτων καὶ ὁ τρό[μος
>   τοῦ σώματος κα[τέχει
>   καὶ μετὰ ταῦτα τ[άδε
>   φησίν· χλωροτ[έρα δὲ
>   π]οίας ἔμμι, τεθ[νάκην
>   δ' ὀ]λίγω δ' ἐπιδε[ύης
>   φα]ίνομ' ἐμαύ[τᾳ

solving that φάινομ line which had different completions, and translating to:

> me the confusion, the sp[inning
>   of the ears and the tre[mor
>   of the body k[eeps
>   and after these things t[hese others
>   she says: green[er than
>   gr]ass I am, and to not have d[ied
>   b[y l]ittle
>   I se]em to mys[elf

Comment: I think your *spinning of the years* is a typo for *ears*.

Comment: @TKR Absolutely. Correcting immediately.